# For loop why the variable out of the loop is "last index" + step?

Tags: c, for-loop, increment

I was just wondering why this :

```
int i;

for (i=0; i<5; i++){

    printf("%d\n",i)

}

printf("Here i get the result that misleads me : %d\n",i)
```

The last value is 5.

My **logic** is :

```
From 0 to 4 -> printf

If i > 4 (since we are dealing with integers) stop the loop.
```

But the loop stopped at 4 not 5 ! Why do I get 5 after the loop ? Why does it ever increment ?

Arbitrary ?

Thanks,

Comment: The loop runs as long as i<5 - that already holds the answer! Because only when i *is* 5 does it stop. So of course it is 5 when it finishes. When it's 4 the break-condition is not yet met.

Comment: @Larry Since we have 7 answers all with zero votes, would you be so kind and select the winner? :) (accept an answer )

Comment: I notice a number of the answers (which seem to be saying the same thing with different words) got an upvote and a down vote, net zero. Strange?

Comment: The most difficult in this situation is to choose a winner ! all the answers are very instructive ! :)

Comment: @Larry - in this case there was no "wrong answer" for you to pick - just the one you found most helpful (as you commented, "plain language"). Glad we were able to help.

Comment: @Floris: bad sportmanship in downvoting those on higher counts of votes.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac - disappointing to think people would try to game the system that way... I hope the majority are better than that.

Comment: Well, just look at many of the newest questions. Multiple answers, as soon as only one gets upvoted some other answerer downvotes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three clauses in the for statement.

1. The init-stmt statement is done before the loop is started, usually
   to initialize an iteration variable.
2. The condition expression is tested before each time the loop is
   done. The loop isn't executed if the boolean expression is false
   (the same as the while loop).
3. The next-stmt statement is done after the body is executed. It
   typically increments an iteration variable.

So, end of each for loop execution, increment operation executed, and, in the 4th iteration, value of i is 5 and the for loop was broke as the value is 5 in 5th iteration.

Comment: It is a nice plain word explanation of what is going on

Comment: Although Fortran behaves the same way, could you please help me understand why this is not the case with Matlab or Python?

Answer (score 2):

unroll what's happening

```
int i = 0;

while( i < 5 )
{
   // body of for loop

   i++;
}

// i == 5 here as i must be greater than or equal to 5 to break out of while loop
```

Answer (score 2):

How does for loop works:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment-decrement)
    Statement
```

1. Run initialization (`i=0`)
2. Check condition (`i<5`), if true then jump to 3 else jump to 5
3. Do statement (`{ printf("%d\n",i) }`)
4. Do increment-decrement (`i++`), jump to 2
5. Exit loop

Before last iteration `i == 4`, then it prints `4`, increments `i`. Therefore after last iteration `i == 5`, `!(5 < 5)`, i.e. condition is false, exit from loop.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of each iteration, the loop index is incremented. Then the program checks whether to run another loop. It finds "no the index is too big and fails the condition", so it doesn't execute and exits.

Until the index gets too big, the condition doesn't fail. It HAS to get too big (so the loop doesn't execute).

And that is why...

Answer (score 1):

Because after the 4th loop:

1. `i++` is performed, `i` becomes 5
2. `i<5` is evaluated as `false`
3. Thus the loop exits

And then you get `i==5` after the end of loop.

Indeed, after each loop, `i++` is evaluated before checking for the exit condition, `i<5`.

Answer (score 1):

`for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)` goes like this:

1. `i <- 0`
2. check whether `i < 5`, if yes, loop, otherwise stop
3. do the loop
4. `i <- i + 1`
5. goes to step 2

Answer (score 0):

Let's see this loop:

```
for (i = 0; 0; i++)
    do_smth();
```

You'll see that this loop doesn't execute at all. Because the condition is false even from the beginning.

Now

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    i++;
```

Clearly increases `i` twice for every run (once inside the loop and **then** because of the third part of the `for`). In the end, `i` will have the first even value which make the condition false. That is `6`. Thus, there is no link between the step and the value of the variable outside the loop.